# Display data from database using base adapter and listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite, baseadapter

i want to display data from SQLite database to my custom listview

this my activity:

```
public class Main_activity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{


public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
    "Banana", "Orange" };

public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
    "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
    "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit"
    };


ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);


rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    RowItem item = new RowItem(titles[i], descriptions[i]);
    rowItems.add(item);
}

listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
    long id) {
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
toast.show();
}
```

in this activity, listview will showing data from string titles and description, now i want replace those string, with my data from sqlite database.
can anyone tell me how can to do that ?

provide tutorial links that lead to the problem is also very helpful

Comment: Access your sqlite database using cursor. Iterate cursor for getting all data and add those data in list. Is you want multiple data , then create cutim list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create database

```
 public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        //Database Version
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        //Database Name
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Test";
        //Table Name
        private static final String TABLE_TEST = "TestTable";
        //Column Name
        private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
        private static final String KEY_AGE = "age";

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        //Create Table
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEST + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_AGE + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TEST);
            onCreate(db);
        }

        //Insert Value
        public void adddata(Context context,String movieId,String songId) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME, movieId);
            values.put(KEY_AGE, songId); 
            db.insert(TABLE_TEST, null, values);
            db.close(); 
        }

        //Get Row Count
        public int getCount() {
            String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEST;
            int count = 0;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            if(cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()){
                count = cursor.getCount();
                cursor.close();
            }   
            return count;
        }

        //Delete Query
        public void removeFav(int id) {
            String countQuery = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TEST + " where " + KEY_ID + "= " + id ;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            db.execSQL(countQuery);
        }

        //Get FavList
        public List<FavoriteList> getFavList(){
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TEST;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            List<FavoriteList> FavList = new ArrayList<FavoriteList>();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    FavoriteList list = new FavoriteList();
                    list.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    list.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    list.setAge(cursor.getString(2));
                    FavList.add(list);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            return FavList;
        }
}
```

and create custom listview using base adapter like below

```
public class ViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ViewAdapter() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return favoriteList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem,null);
            }

            final TextView nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
            nameText.setText("Name : "+favoriteList.get(position).getName());
            final TextView ageText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ageText);
            ageText.setText("Age : "+favoriteList.get(position).getAge());

            final Button edit = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
            edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.row);
                    dialog.setTitle("Add Data to Database");
                    final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    final EditText age = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.age);
                    Button Add = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Add);
                    Add.setText("Add");
                    Add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if(name.getText().toString() != null && name.getText().toString().length() >0 ){
                                if(age.getText().toString() != null && age.getText().toString().length() >0 ){
                                    db.updateRow(favoriteList.get(position).getId(), name.getText().toString(), age.getText().toString());
                                    favoriteList = db.getFavList();
                                    listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter the Age", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                                }
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter the Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();  
                }
            });
            final Button delete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    db.removeFav(favoriteList.get(position).getId());
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    favoriteList = db.getFavList();
                    listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
                }
            });
            return convertView;
        }
    }
```

Get data from database:

```
favoriteList = db.getFavList();
```

finally add adapter

```
listView.setAdapter(new ViewAdapter());
```

If you need more help please see the below Url

http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/04/android-sqlite-with-custom-listview.html

Comment: i have small question: what it is R.id.name ...... where as there is no such id is written in xml and simularly Add is not written????. plz specify as i am also new in android. also what is row in dialog.setContentView(R.layout.row);?????????